# Работа с определенной датой

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

[image: Таблица]

Нужно вывести сколько задач на конец дня, имеют статус 1 или 2. При сортировке по дате вывод должен быть следующим.
(2017-12-29)- одна задача с task_id=3 в статусе 1 на конец суток - итог 1 new 0 completed
(2018-01-01) - две задачи всего у одной (task_id=1) в статусе 3 на конец суток + task_id=3 из предыдущей даты осталась со статусом 1 итог 1 new 0 completed
(2018-01-02) - новая задача task_id=2 + все старые - итог 2 new 0 completed

```
SELECT
  date(timestamp) as 'date',
  count(case when status_type = '1' then 1 else 0 end) as number_of_new,
  count(case when status_type = '2' then 1 else 0 end) as number_of_completed
FROM incident_table
where timestamp >= (select max(timestamp) - date('now', '-30 days') from incident_table)
group by date(timestamp)
```

я делал так, но это совершенно не то, мне нужно как то работать с датой, я не знаю как это сделать, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Выведите ожидаемый результат в формате таблицы. Совсем нечитабельно

Comment: + версию базы данных